# How to hide a menu on anything but a click on the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a link which is a persons username. When you click it, a little flyout window (an unordered list) appears. I'm trying to make it so:

1. Clicking on the persons username toggles the flyout ul with fadein/out
2. If you click to show the flyout, and click ON the ul, it doesnt disappear
3. if you click on the body anywhere except the flyout, it disappears

This is what I have so far but I'm basically just fooling myself into thinking I know what I'm doing :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flyout h3 a').click(function() {
        var flyout = $('.flyout ul');
        flyout.fadeToggle(80,function() {
            if ( flyout.is(':visible') ) {
                console.log('visible');
                $(document).on('click',function(e) {
                    flyout.fadeOut(80);
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            } else {
                $(document).off('click');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="flyout">
                <h3>Welcome back, <a href="#">Dogbreath</a><img src="img/down-arrow.png" alt="dropdown"></h3>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon">&#128101;</span>Users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon">&#128360;</span>Groups</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon">&#9881;</span>Configuration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="icon">&#59201;</span>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You said what you are trying to do, but not what the problem is. So which part is not working?

Comment: all of it really.. it goes away when its not supposed to when you click on just the menu, and when you click it the first time it shows up. if you click the name it hides. but if you click the name again (to show it a second time) it shows and hides instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to do too much in the callback function for `fadeToggle()`

try just having something like this (untested)

```
$flyout = $('.flyout ul');
$('.flyout h3 a').click(function() { $flyout.fadeToggle(80) }
```

this takes care of hiding/showing the menu when the username is clicked, no?

then, separately and independently, bind events on `document`(this might take some tweaking)

```
// any click on document element that isn't a child of flyout, closes flyout
$(document).on('click',function(e) { if ($(e.target).parents($flyout).length == 0 $flyout.fadeOut() });
```

Comment: interesting, trying now. tahnks

Comment: sorry, `$flyout` was just supposed to be a jQuery object for the dom element you want to show/hide.

Comment: Wow magical. In so little code too..... what does the $ before the variable signify?

Comment: the `$` is just a naming convention you see some people use, it indicates the variable is a jQuery selector/object. It has no actual effect. Glad it's working, enjoy

Comment: what I dont get is how is clicking the UL itself not making it disappear? $('.flyout ul').parents('.flyout ul') returns [], so wouldnt clicking the ul itself (as opposed to the links) make it disappear? the links dont take up 100% of the space so its still possible to click the ul

Comment: hmm, good question, I can't say for sure. In the debugger, look at what `e.target` is when you click the `ul`